# Is there a shortcut to get to the bottom of a long email on iPad or iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I get some long emails in which the important stuff is at the bottom after many pages. It is tedious to scroll down.  Is there a way to get to the bottom quickly? Either for iPhone iPad or both.

Comment: This is an issue in other applications in iPad and iPhone, for instance long web pages. I wish I knew a solution to both going to the bottom and to the top of a web page in Safari.

Comment: @lhf to go to the top of a page in safari is easy, just tap the bar at the top (where the battery icon lives)... going to the bottom, I'm in the dark there though

Answer (score 11, accepted):

iOS does not provide a shortcut for skipping directly to the bottom of documents, but there is a reasonable alternative, if you're not already aware of it: scrolling views in iOS respond to *swipe frequency*, scrolling more quickly the more quickly and frequently you swipe the screen.

While swiping a long document, email, or webpage, try several long, quick swipes in rapid succession: you should notice the scrolling speed accelerate accordingly. This isn't nearly as elegant as a tap shortcut, but does let you quickly skip to the bottom of a long view.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid no such shortcut exists.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the following bookmark which will scroll you to the bottom of the page:

```
javascript:scroll(0,document.getElementsByTagName( %22body%22)%5B0%5D.scrollHeight);
```

<sup>Source: http://www.ipadforums.net/ipad-help/69590-quickly-go-bottom-page.html</sup>

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While the link you provided may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. I've edited your question to include what I believe was the solution that you were referring to, however if it wasn't please quote the relevant section.

Comment: How does this help an iOS user?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround I just figured out:  Just make a comment at the top and bottom of the document.  When you view the top comment, you can then use the < in the comment navigation to quickly go to the bottom comment.  As mentioned before, you can quickly navigate to the top at any time by tapping the clock in the topbar.  Even if you make a lot of comments, you can always navigate < from the top to the very last comment.  You can also make comments as chapter, indexing, or placeholding markers and quickly navigate large documents.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Try double tapping at either side of the screen at the edge

Comment: Hi Kate and welcome to Ask Different.  In an effort to help improve your answer, you should consider adding some contextual information, explanations or links/references that give further detail as to why you believe your answer is correct.